# Unable to access global variable from function

Tags: javascript, variables, global, onblur

I am trying to set the `numberTotal` as a global variable so I can access it outside of the `cardNum_auto` function. It is being triggered by the onblur in the input field of the form. I need to access it to populate the URL at the bottom. If I place it all in the function it works but creates multiple buttons.

```
<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
  <form id="golf-card-tally">
    <h3 style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 0px;">ORDER YOURS TODAY!!</h3>
    <div style="width: 400px; display: inline-block;">
      <div style="margin-bottom:10px">
        <div style="text-align:center">
          <h3>Enter Number of Cards</h3>
        </div>
        <div><input id="cardNum" type="number" onblur="cardNum_auto(this)" /></div>
      </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="golf-card-tally"></div>
```

```
var numberTotal;

function cardNum_auto(input) {
  numberTotal = input.value;
  console.log("numberTotal " + numberTotal + " in the function!");
}

console.log("numberTotal " + numberTotal + " out of the function!");

var golfCardDiv = document.createElement('div');
golfCardDiv.innerHTML = '<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; margin-bottom: 20px;"><button style="border: 0px; border-radius: 18px;height:38px; width: 160px; color: white; font-weight: bold; background-color: #417505; cursor: pointer;"onclick="window.open(\'https://google.com?m=9272&amp;amount=' + numberTotal + '&amp;invoice=\')"type="submit">Submit Payment</button></div>';
var element = document.getElementById("golf-card-tally");
element.appendChild(golfCardDiv);
```

Comment: I recommend reading this [excellent book](http://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/scope-closures/README.md) - especially chapters 3 and 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i see is a button is created each time the input loses focus. It is because the input keeps the event listener. You should remove the event listener in your function `cardNum_auto`.
To do that, you can't call `cardNum_auto` from the html and declare it in your script.

in your HTML

```
<div><input id="cardNum" type="number"/></div>
```

in JS

```
var numberTotal;

function cardNum_auto() {
    input.removeEventListener('blur',cardNum_auto)
    numberTotal = input.value;
    var golfCardDiv = document.createElement('div');
    golfCardDiv.innerHTML = '<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; margin-bottom: 20px;"><button style="border: 0px; border-radius: 18px;height:38px; width: 160px; color: white; font-weight: bold; background-color: #417505; cursor: pointer;"onclick="window.open(\'https://google.com?m=9272&amp;amount=' + numberTotal + '&amp;invoice=\')"type="submit">Submit Payment</button></div>';
    var element = document.getElementById("golf-card-tally");
    element.appendChild(golfCardDiv);
}

let input = document.querySelector('#cardNum')
input.addEventListener('blur',cardNum_auto)
```